# Common Dependency Module Causing Main Class Not Found Error in Multi-Module Maven Project"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am encountering an issue with a multi-module Maven project. When I run the application within IntelliJ IDEA, everything compiles and runs smoothly. However, when I attempt to build the project using the Maven wrapper from the terminal with the command ./mvnw clean install -DskipTests, I encounter a compilation error indicating that none of the classes included in the common module can be found. Here is a portion of the error output:

[image: project structure]

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for event_driven_design_eshop 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] event_driven_design_eshop .......................... SUCCESS [  1.136 s]
[INFO] api_gateway ........................................ SUCCESS [  2.227 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.174 s]
[INFO] eshop-core ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.173 s]
[INFO] order_service ...................................... FAILURE [  0.708 s]
[INFO] product_service .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] user-service ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] payment-service .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] shipping-service ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] discovery_server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.855 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-13T19:32:08+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project order_service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/jchaaban/IdeaProjects/event_driven_design_eshop/eshop_core/order_service/src/main/java/com/jchaaban/orders_service/handler/query/OrderFetchingHandler.java:[3,33] package com.jchaaban.common.query does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jchaaban/IdeaProjects/event_driven_design_eshop/eshop_core/order_service/src/main/java/com/jchaaban/orders_service/repository/OrderEntity.java:[3,33] package com.jchaaban.common.model does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jchaaban/IdeaProjects/event_driven_design_eshop/eshop_core/order_service/src/main/java/com/jchaaban/orders_service/handler/query/OrderFetchingHandler.java:[26,36] cannot find symbol
....
```

so all the classes in the common modules are not found.

After this, if I try to run the application in the IDE, I get an error stating that the main class of the first module
in the list of the child modules of the eshop_module cannot be found.

Let us say this is the list of modules in the eshop_module/pom.xml

```
    <modules>
        <module>order_service</module>
        <module>product_service</module>
        <module>user_service</module>
        <module>payment_service</module>
        <module>shipping_service</module>
    </modules>
```

After running the services in IntelliJ, the main class of order_service cannot be located.
If I rearrange the module order so that product_service is listed first, the same issue occurs
for the product_service main class.

As a temporary solution, I've found that changing the root package name (in the service where I'm encountering the issue,
such as order_service) allows me to run the project in the IDE once more.
However, if I subsequently attempt to run it with Maven in the terminal, the error resurfaces, necessitating the
repetition of the same process to restore functionality in IntelliJ.

This issue persists for each service depending on the common module.

This is the pom file of the root project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
    <artifactId>event_driven_design_eshop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>event_driven_design_eshop</name>
    <description>event_driven_design_eshop</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>api_gateway</module>
        <module>eshop_core</module>
        <module>discovery_server</module>
        <module>common</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the pom.xml file of the common module, which is a dependency of the eshop_core and therefore it will be a dependency of each submodule of eshop_core:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>event_driven_design_eshop</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>common</name>
    <description>common</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the pom file of eshop_core which is a child module of the root project and the parent of all other modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>event_driven_design_eshop</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>order_service</module>
        <module>product_service</module>
        <module>user_service</module>
        <module>payment_service</module>
        <module>shipping_service</module>
    </modules>

    <artifactId>eshop_core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eshop-core</name>
    <description>eshop-core</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Now the child modules of the eshop_core, order_service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>eshop_core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>order_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>order_service</name>
    <description>order_service</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hdrhistogram</groupId>
            <artifactId>HdrHistogram</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

payment_service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>eshop_core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>payment_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>payment-service</name>
    <description>payment-service</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

product_service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>eshop_core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>product_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>product_service</name>
    <description>product_service</description>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

shipping_service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>eshop_core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>shipping_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shipping-service</name>
    <description>shipping-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

user_service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jchaaban</groupId>
        <artifactId>eshop_core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>user_service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-service</name>
    <description>user-service</description>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there any specific reason for this error?

Comment: Your common module ` <artifactId>common</artifactId>` uses the spring-boot-maven-plugin which packages as a spring boot app which means you can not consume it as a usualy dependency... In common I doubt that you create a startable jar file which will be executed... so remove the spring boot maven-plugin from that module.... also build on plain command line... via `mvn clean verify` ...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I attempted the suggested solution, but unfortunately, it did not work. Is there a specific approach I should follow? Currently, I am executing 'mvn clean install -DskipTests' or 'mvn clean verify' in the root project. Do I need to build the submodules separately beforehand?

Comment: Can you put that on a github repo or alike...

Comment: I resolved the issue. The core of the lay in the project structure: the root project was configured as a child of org.springframework.boot, with the common module also being its subproject. This inadvertently led to the common module being treated as a Spring Boot project, which was not the intended setup since it's merely a dependency project. So, I removed the 'parent' tag from the common module's configuration and this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if you are use this modules like a library project, you have to tell the build system to not try to build an executable jar for the these project (order_service and product_service). For this you must remove the following block from these modules(pom):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/